# Getting game object coordinate (from world coordinate) in screen coordinate [Unity3D]

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have an object (say, a human) in my game which is in 3D. I want to know the coordinate of that human (in terms of pixels i.e. x and y) when I take a screenshot of the view from my main camera?

To take the screenshot, I am using this [link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ScreenshotMovie).

Any pointers?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

Comment: @JonasGrumann: I am using a spline controller to move that human. So, what should be my "target" in WorldToScreenPoint script?

Comment: target would be your gameObject's transform (in your case the human). If you attach this script to the human you can use Vector3 screenPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

Comment: @JonasGrumann I have made an answer from your comment so that it is easier for everyone else to look up when needed. If you want to post yours I will delete mine :)

Comment: No it's fine, actually, I'll upvote so you can get the points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need this: [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint();](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)